# elevatezoom set width to division width

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, zooming

I am using [elevateZoom](http://www.elevateweb.co.uk/image-zoom) and display of the image is set to a division. I want the zoomed image to be the division's width. If the division width is fixed we can use zoomWindowWidth option which they provided but Division width changes according to the browser or device.
Is there any configuration or any other way?

```
<img id="zoom_04c" src="images/small/image.png" 
data-zoom-image="images/large/image.jpg"/>
<br />
<div id="demo-container" class="col-md-4"></div>
<script>
$("#zoom_04c").elevateZoom({
    zoomWindowPosition: "demo-container",
    borderSize: 2,
    easing:false});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats a tricky thing. There are lots of calculations happening to get the zooming right.
In addition to use the 'zoomContainerAppendTo' option that was added to EZP.
You may want to listen to the width of the container, and re-initialize the plugin. (to add the dynamic feeling)

Comment: *Disclaimer: i'm the maintainer of those free MIT open source project.*